# make a static method for all classes in PHP using meta class Class?

Tags: php, class, metaprogramming

How can I add a static method for all classes of my php using an class Class or class Object (meta class) like

```
class Object //meta class, all classes php henerit of it
{
    static function test() { return 42; }
}
```

now if I make a new class like :

```
class User
{
}
```

I want to be abble to write :

```
User::test();
```

same with all classes I will write

Comment: Traits: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: You could make a MyClass class and make sure that all of your classes extend it (directly or indirectly). It's not as all-encompassing as what you're looking for, but I think many would argue that's actually a feature, not a bug. Your proposal would change the behaviour of all third-party libraries you might ever use, potentially breaking them (as some will surely have their own `test` function that is critical, but would break with your change).

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no concept of [metaclasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass); the way in which classes themselves behave is essentially hard-coded into the language. (You could argue that internal classes written in C conceptually use a different metaclass than userland classes written in PHP, since they can implement a different set of hooks; but that's not a distinction that's visible in the language, and not really relevant to your example.)

It also has no universal base class; there is no "Object" or "Any" or "Mu" class which all other classes implicitly or explicitly inherit from.

More importantly, there is no way to add to an existing class; there is no way to "re-open" or "monkey-patch" a class, or add methods via "extension classes". So even if there was a default metaclass or universal base class, you wouldn't be able to change it. Any classes you wanted extra behaviour on would have to opt-in to being instances of a non-default metaclass, or inherit from a non-default base class.

It's not clear exactly what the use case is, but there are a number of things you *can* do:

- Write your own base class which a large number of classes inherit from, to put your "universal" methods in.
- Use [traits](https://php.net/traits) which enable "horizontal code re-use", essentially by "compiler-assisted copy-and-paste".

  - You have to `use` the trait in each class where you want to "paste" its contents, but they will then be inherited from there, so you can have a handful of unrelated "base classes" all sharing a set of methods "pasted" from the same trait.
  - On the other hand, you might want to create a *sub-class* which takes an existing class and adds some methods using a trait.
- More complex cases would require you to patch the source code of classes themselves. For instance, using a custom autoloader and https://github.com/nikic/php-parser to parse and manipulate class definitions before they are compiled. For instance, this [just-for-fun sweary library](https://github.com/jaem3l/unfuck) installs as a Composer plugin and loads classes via a stream wrapper which removes restrictions such as "final".

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a trait?

Unfortunately I haven't heard of anything like what you need in PHP.

```
<?php

trait Obj
{
    static function test() { return 42; }
}

class User
{
    use Obj;
}

echo User::test(); //prints 42
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I was hoping PHP8 is better for metaprogramming...